# iOS 13 CoreData [NSManagedObjectContext _thereIsNoSadnessLikeTheDeathOfOptimism].cold.1

Tags: core-data, ios13

Starting iOS 13 i have this crash on Core Data.

[image]

I have also this log from crash:

error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure.  Old save request was:  { inserts ((
    "0xadc166d0638c99fd "
)), updates (), deletes () locks () }
CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure.  Old save request was:  { inserts ((
    "0xadc166d0638c99fd "
)), updates (), deletes () locks () }
 [error] error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure.  Next attempt will be:  { inserts ((
    "0xadc166d0638c99fd "
)), updates (), deletes () locks () }
CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure.  Next attempt will be:  { inserts ((
    "0xadc166d0638c99fd "
)), updates (), deletes () locks () }
[error] error: fatal: Unable to recover from optimistic locking failure.
CoreData: error: fatal: Unable to recover from optimistic locking failure.

It seems to be a conflict issue, but i tried all types of merge policy but no results.

Comment: Do you think it may have something to do with the second line in the error message? That could explain why your code suffers an optimistic locking failure... so how do you create your main thread context and do you, intentionally or otherwise, at some point in your code pass it to a background thread?

Comment: I don't think it's related to second line. Now the context is for main thread, but in the past was something related to background thread. This crash occurs for 1% percent of users. It's something related to iCloud, because i reproduce following this steps: 1. delete the app; 2. i put a fresh install and i have no entries. 3. i wait some seconds to come from iCloud and at a point is crashes. And after i reopen the app it crashes again after some seconds. And no entries.

Comment: Starting iOS 13.2 the crash is fixed. :)